# Select distinct child array properties LoDash

Tags: lodash, distinct-values

With the following model structure:

```
prods: [{
        code: 'ABC123',
        name: 'Product 1',
        variants[{
                code: 'V123',
                name 'Var 1'
            }, {
                code: 'V456',
                name 'Var 2'
            }, {
                code: 'V789',
                name 'Var 3'
            }
        ]
    }, {
        code: 'DEF456',
        name: 'Product 2',
        variants[{
                code: 'V098',
                name 'Var 4'
            }, {
                code: 'V123',
                name 'Var 1'
            }, {
                code: 'V123',
                name 'Var 1'
            }
        ]
    }, {
        code: 'XYZ123',
        name: 'Product 3',
        variants[{
                code: 'V123',
                name 'Var 1'
            }, {
                code: 'V456',
                name 'Var 2'
            }, {
                code: 'V789',
                name 'Var 3'
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Is it possible to get an array of the unique variant codes, so would expect output to give me:

> [{code:'V123'},{code: 'V456'}, {code: 'V789'},{code: 'V098'}]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can chain together [map()](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#map), [flatten()](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#flatten), and [uniqBy()](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#uniqBy):

```
_(prods)
  .map('variants')
  .flatten()
  .uniqBy('code')
  .map(i => _.pick(i, 'code'))
  .value();
```

The second `map()` call isn't strictly necessary - it's just to get rid of the `name` property to match your requested output.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [flatMap](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#flatMap) to get all variants, complemented with [map](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#map) and [uniqBy](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#uniqBy) to get all unique codes.

```
var result = _(prods)
  .flatMap('variants')
  .uniqBy('code')
  .map(_.partialRight(_.pick, 'code'))
  .value();
```

```js
var prods = [{
  code: 'ABC123',
  name: 'Product 1',
  variants: [{
    code: 'V123',
    name: 'Var 1'
  }, {
    code: 'V456',
    name: 'Var 2'
  }, {
    code: 'V789',
    name: 'Var 3'
  }]
}, {
  code: 'DEF456',
  name: 'Product 2',
  variants: [{
    code: 'V098',
    name: 'Var 4'
  }, {
    code: 'V123',
    name: 'Var 1'
  }, {
    code: 'V123',
    name: 'Var 1'
  }]
}, {
  code: 'XYZ123',
  name: 'Product 3',
  variants: [{
    code: 'V123',
    name: 'Var 1'
  }, {
    code: 'V456',
    name: 'Var 2'
  }, {
    code: 'V789',
    name: 'Var 3'
  }]
}];

var result = _(prods)
  .flatMap('variants')
  .uniqBy('code')
  .map(_.partialRight(_.pick, 'code'))
  .value();
  
console.log(result);
```

```css
body > div { min-height: 100%; top: 0; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.js"></script>
```